# How to set the font size of the label on pushbutton in Qt?

Tags: qt4, qpushbutton

I am using this code to set a label on the pushbutton with size of 16

```
ui->pushButton->setText(tr("<font size=16>Tank 1 \n %1%2C</font>").arg(szTemp).arg(degree));
```

but I am getting the output as `<font size=16>Tank 1 005c</font>` written on pushbutton.

How to set the font size?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The text value of a `QPushButton` is not "rich text" so it will not interpret your html as expected. Either use the `setFont` on your widget to set the font size, or set it via a style sheet:

```
QFont font = ui->pushButton->font();
font.setPointSize(16);
ui->pushButton->setFont(font);
```

Style sheets, while more powerful, can tend to be a bit more complex because it forces you to define a number of other features that you are now over-writting.

Answer (score 7):

you can use style sheets

```
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);background-color: rgb(38,56,76);}");
```

Answer (score 2):

In **PyQT5**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

# some code here

btn = QPushButton()
btn.setFont(QFont('Times', 20))

# some code here
```