# Unable to increase size of QToolButton (with Button style set to Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)

Tags: c++, qt, font-size, qtoolbutton

I have a small `qt` application written in `c++`. I want the same application to run in small embedded device with a touchscreen but the size of few `QToolButton` was too small to be visible comfortably. I have tired to increase the size by modifying following function (adding `setfont` member call):

```
QToolButton* ColorToolBar::setupToolButton(QString name, QString iconPath, bool isCheckable)
{
    QToolButton *p_btn = new QToolButton(this);
    p_btn->setCheckable(isCheckable);
    p_btn->setIcon(QIcon(iconPath));
    p_btn->setIconSize(QSize(ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT));
    p_btn->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon);

    QFont font = p_btn->font();
    font.setPointSize(10);
    p_btn->setFont(font);

    if (!name.isEmpty())
        p_btn->setText(name);

    p_btn->setMinimumWidth(MINIMUM_WIDTH);
    p_btn->setMinimumHeight(MINIMUM_HEIGHT);
    return p_btn;
}
```

I am able to change the `Icon size` using `setIconSize` member function but `setPointSize` and `setFont` doesn't do anything. I want to have larger text and icon.

I have a class `AdvancePlotToolBar` which has all the QToolButton.My `qss` file looks like :

```
AdvancePlotToolBar QToolButton {
  border: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px; 
}
AdvancePlotToolBar QToolButton:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #52ce90;
  padding-bottom: 5px; 
}
AdvancePlotToolBar QToolButton:pressed {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #52ce90; 
}
AdvancePlotToolBar QToolButton:checked {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #52ce90;
  margin: 0px; 
}
```

**EDIT:**

The code below shows how I add `QToolButton` to the layout of `AdvancePlotToolbar`.

```
AdvancePlotToolBar::AdvancePlotToolBar(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    transformationButton_ =  setupToolButton("Transformations", "://images//summation.png", true);

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    layout->addWidget(transformationButton_);
    setLayout(layout);

}
```

Comment: As the widget-size (possibly) depends on the way you insert the widget into your layout, you should post the relevant code that does that. Currently we see only the initialization code of the button, but the layout code is missing.

Comment: Updated my question with required code.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example reproducing this issue? Not being cheeky... :) just investigating. There is definitely some inconsistent behavior surrounding fonts and what inherits from what and when, and I've ID'd at least one Qt bug so far with `Qt::AA_UseStyleSheetPropagationInWidgetStyles` flag even when not using CSS at all. And having `QStyleSheetStyle` involved makes "unexpected" differences. But... **I can't actually reproduce what you describe** when setting font explicitly on the `QToolButton`s. I think you may be setting a font somewhere else as well? I'd love to repro it. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a style sheet is overriding the font size you're setting in the C++ code. Try it w/out any style sheet applied (even to `QApplication`) and check. (Also [How to set the font size of the label on pushbutton in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984811/how-to-set-the-font-size-of-the-label-on-pushbutton-in-qt) )

I have the same issue with a completely custom `QToolButton` which overrides `initStyleOption()` and sets own font details in there (so it happens each time just before the button is painted, unrelated to `setFont()` at all).  This works until an app-wide style-sheet is applied (even if it doesn't affect `QToolButton` directly! *), or a style sheet is applied specifically to the button instance or to its parent. I haven't tracked down where exactly this is happening (somewhere in `QStyleSheetStyle` I imagine), so I do not have a workaround yet **. In your case since you're using CSS for the tool button anyway, that would probably be best place to set the font size as well.

* The reason setting a style sheet may affect elements which are not styled specifically in the CSS rules is that the whole underlying `QStyle` is replaced with `QStyleSheetStyle`, and the original style (Fusion, WindowsVista, Macintosh, etc) becomes a proxy/fallback for `QStyleSheetStyle`. Or IOW all painting is filtered through the CSS style first. This includes setting style sheet on individual elements as well as globally on `QApplication`.

** I suspect this is a Qt bug.